# RatingBar change size when scale it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hello I am working with RattingBar and I have a problem. I need scale it to reduce the star size. The problem is when I scale it, the star size is smoller but the content of the start is the same. You can see it in the images:

[image: Without scale]

[image: With scale]

How I could reduce content size and star size?

this is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/card_comment">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="120dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80E6E6E6">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5"
                android:gravity="start"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="5.0"
                android:stepSize="0.0" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="comentario"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!!

Edit: when I change linearlayout (vertical) like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

I am getting this stars:

[image]

How I could solve it?

thank you

Comment: do You mean way to change the TextView content width? or just the text size?

Comment: I am asking about ratingBar, how you can see, it doesn't get all height space, but it cut the stars

Answer (score 1):

in XML Change this:

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:stepSize="0.5"
android:scaleX="0.5"
android:scaleY="0.5"
android:theme="@style/RatingBar" />
```

In Style

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
</style>
```